# how to name java hashmap local var in java language?

Tags: java

as titled:

how to name java hashmap local var  in java language?

```
private static volatile Map<String, Session> ip_Session_Map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Session>();
```

key is ip, value is session?

how to name the map?

ipSessionMap? ip_Session_Map? ipToSessionMap? or others? which is best?

Comment: Anything that is clear is fine, personally I'd go with `ipSessionMap`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the naming conventions used by your group. If you are using upper and lower camel case then as this is an instance of a class you would use LCC;

ipSessionMap

Answer (score 1):

The naming convention typically used in Java programs is CamelCase, starting with lower case for internal variables and upper case for class names.  See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

This means the variable should be named something like "ipSessionMap."

My personal preference would be to leave out the "to."  Some would prefer to also leave out the type information ("Map") from the variable name.  I've never been big on hungarian notation.

Answer (score 1):

Java naming convention opts for camel case:

1. Class names will always start with upper case: MyClassName
2. variable and function names will start with lower case: myNewVariable, myFunction()

using '_' in variable names is PHP convention.

Look [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of Java Style says,

> Use lowercase for the first word and capitalize only the first letter
>   of each  subsequent word that appears in a variable name.

also refere [Sun Java Coding Convention](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf)

according to those documents, ipSessionMap looks good. Even Sun Java Source Code follow this same standard in most places. But to follow this convention or not purely depends on the interest of your team you work with.So adhere to the coding conventions of your team.